# WinApp title bar icon

Tags: c#

In my desktop application, i am using a 128x128 .ico file in runtime.

```
public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.MyIcon;
}
```

It looks good in task bar, but hazy in title bar. I am using win8 (64bit). Is there any trick to overcome this problem?

!!! UPDATE !!!
[image]

Comment: Some screenshots will be good to see

Comment: I think icon files can include multiple sizes and windows will use the appropriately sized icon where it's valid, might want to check that out.

Comment: @David Heffernan, would you please add a little detail?

Answer (score 3):

Icons (.ico files) support multiple sizes/versions of a given image. Make sure you have all of the appropriate sizes embedded in your icon.

There are a handful of free icon editors out there, Visual Studio has a (pretty poor) icon editor build in. I've used [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/) successfully in the past, which has a 30 day free demo. I'm there there are other free ones out there as well, including a plugin for Photoshop.

You can see the VS icon editor (with the multiple formats below):
[image]

Comment: @David Heffernan: He's referring to the .ico format, not the `Icon` class. At least, that's what I read based on the rest of his answer.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of the ico image format so perhaps I need to be more specific. System.Drawling.Icon is a representation of an .ico file, which is meant to house multiple images in different sizes. An application will pick the most appropriate image to display at runtime. So an application icon in a detail exporer view might use the smallest, if you change the view to large icons, it will use a larger version of the image. My answer, while perhaps not 100% clear, is correct.

Comment: That's how I understood it as well.

Comment: @Bolt OK, it's more complex than this. It is true that `Icon` only has one image. But it also caches from where that image was loaded. That allows for this constructor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fhec722.aspx) which goes back to the original source of the icon and fetches a new image of a different size. It seems that the framework is more than clever enough to take advantage of this functionality of `Icon`. So, this answer is indeed good. +1